# How do I retrieve the unresolved path which contains dynamic segments?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Is it possible to retrieve the unresolved path (`dashboard/:companyId`) of the currently active route?
Every hook/utility I tested only returns `dashboard/abc`.

My specific usecase:
**I have a global (app-wide) company picker which should replace the `companyId` regardless of the current route.**
So my idea would be to retrieve the unresolved route + params. Then check if there's a `companyId` and if so, resolve it with the new `companyId`.
Or is there a better solution for this?

#### Expectation

```
const params = useParams();
const unresolvedRoute = use???(); // -> 'dashboard/:companyId'

if(params.companyId) {
  const newCompany = 'xyz';
  const newPath = generatePath(unresolvedRoute, { companyId: newCompany });
}
```

Should work for any route which contains a `:companyId`

```
/dashboard/company1 -> /dashboard/company
/dashboard/company1/details -> /dashboard/company2/details
/settings/company1 -> /settings/company2
```

Comment: What is the *actual* use case here, navigating to `"/dashboard/:companyId"` with a new `companyId` value? Why does this code need to "guess" where it is trying to compute a target path to? Can you clarify the wider scope of this code? You may need to [edit] to include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese The use case is that the company can change globally (e.g. dropdown in the header) whilst keeping all the static route parts.
So it should be like, "change to company XY wherever you are" and not explicitly "go to dashboard of company XY".

Comment: Sorry, I meant the code logic use case, not the business use case. It's clear you want to dynamically change the `companyId` route path parameter. ***How*** you accomplish this sort of depends on ***where*** the logic lives. Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] that includes the router and routes, various routed components that are relevant, and where you are wanting/trying to change the `companyId` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not any "native" RRDv6 way really to get the pattern that was used, but I think you could solve this in a couple basic ways.

- Use the [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) utility function and an array of path patterns that *can* be matched and find/return the matching path pattern. Iterate the array of path patterns and return the one with a non-null `match` object.

  ```
  import {
    ...
    matchPath as matchPathBase,
    useLocation,
    useNavigate,
    generatePath,
    ...
  } from "react-router-dom";

  const matchPath = (patterns, pathname) =>
    [patterns].flat().find((pattern) => matchPathBase(pattern, pathname));

  ...

  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const pattern = matchPath(
    [
      "/dashboard/:companyId",
      "/dashboard/:companyId/details",
      "/settings/:companyId"
    ],
    pathname
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (pattern) {
      navigate(generatePath(pattern, { companyId }), { replace: true });
    }
  }, [companyId, navigate, pattern]);
  ```

  [image: Edit how-do-i-retrieve-the-unresolved-path-which-contains-dynamic-segments (matchPath)]
- Use the [`useMatches`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches) hook to return an array of matches and access the one with a defined handle that was provided to the route you want to get the pattern for. Use a Data router and add a `handle` prop object with a `pattern` property to each route you want to access a pattern for, then use the `useMatches` hook to find the match entry with a defined `handle` property (*i.e. non-null match objects will have it*).

  ```
  import {
    ...
    useNavigate,
    generatePath,
    useMatches,
    ...
  } from "react-router-dom";

  ...

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const matches = useMatches();

  const [companyId, setCompanyId] = React.useState("123");

  const { pattern } = matches.find((match) => match.handle)?.handle || {};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (pattern) {
      navigate(generatePath(pattern, { companyId }), { replace: true });
    }
  }, [companyId, navigate, pattern]);
  ```

  ```
  import {
    createBrowserRouter,
    RouterProvider
  } from "react-router-dom";

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/dashboard",
          children: [
            {
              path: ":companyId",
              children: [
                {
                  index: true,
                  element: <CompanyDashboard />,
                  handle: {
                    pattern: "/dashboard/:companyId"
                  }
                },
                {
                  path: "details",
                  element: <CompanyDetails />,
                  handle: {
                    pattern: "/dashboard/:companyId/details"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: "/settings",
          children: [
            {
              path: ":companyId",
              children: [
                {
                  index: true,
                  element: <SettingsDashboard />,
                  handle: {
                    pattern: "/settings/:companyId"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);

  ...

  <RouterProvider router={router} />
  ```

  [image: Edit how-do-i-retrieve-the-unresolved-path-which-contains-dynamic-segments (useMatches)]